# PyCharm does not recognize nested class overriding

Tags: python, class, pycharm, overriding, inner-classes

I have the following class:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_object = self.NestedClass()

    class NestedClass:
        def __init__(self):
            self.name = "abc"
```

PyCharm recognizes NestedClass as a nested class of A:

```py
A.NestedClass # This autocompletes fine
```

However, NestedClass is annoyingly ignored when it comes to overriding it from an inheriting class:

```py
class B(A):
    def get_name(self): # This autocompletes just fine
        return super().get_name()
    
    class NestedClass:
        # Is neither recognized in code completion nor seen as overriding A.NestedClass by PyCharm
        # even though it functions the same as an overridden class variable or method when run
        def __init__(self):
            self.name = "xyz"
```

Is this a bug or lacking feature? Or do I need to change something in the settings to get the desired behavior?

Comment: How exactly do you want it to be "recognized"?  What are you trying to do, and what is happening instead?

Comment: @Samwise As stated in the post, an overridden nested class is not being treated the same by PyCharm as methods and variables are. The biggest issue with this being the classes will not show up in code completion. There is also no symbol indicating it is overridden when one would expect it to be there, which could make certain errors slightly harder to catch.